# Linux kernel supports live-core option in userspace process

Tags: linux, gdb, kernel, bsd

Is there any known solution in linux to take live-core of a process without killing it. From the initial pointers to in-depth search I can see using gcore and gdb centric methods. Is there any concrete way to take a live snapshot of a process for offline analysis without killing it. Just like we use ddb in BSD's?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any concrete way to take a live snapshot of a process for offline analysis without killing it.

Yes: GDB and `gcore`.

Alternatively, you can link in Google user-space [coredumper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/) and call it from within the process as desired.

Comment: Do this stop the process before taking livecore

Comment: @paavaanan Yes, but so does the kernel.